# Given that you started with one chip, what is the probability that you will win this game?

Tags: probability, recursion, gambling

The game is:

> You start with one chip. You flip a fair coin. If it throws heads, you gain
>   one chip. If it throws tails, you lose one chip. If you have zero
>   chips, you lose the game. If you have three chips, you win. What is the
>   probability that you will win this game?

My attempt is:

Let $p$ be the probability that you win. If you throw two heads in a row ($\frac{1}{4}$ probability of this happening), then you win the game. If you throw heads and then tails ($\frac{1}{4}$ probability of this happening), then you start over (and hence probability of you winning the game is $p$ at this point). So setting up the recursion gives

$$p = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}p \implies \frac{3}{4}p = \frac{1}{4} \implies p = \frac{1}{3}$$

Is it correct?

Comment: I agree with your logic and answer.

Comment: You can check yourself by computing probability of loosing the game, using the same logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more pedant answer...

The game has a model given by the following Markov chain with states $0, 1, 2, 3$ (naturally associated
to the number of coins we have in the hand):

```
       1/2        1/2        1/2
     <----      <----      <---- 
 [0]       [1]        [2]        [3]
 LOSE     START                  WIN
      ---->      ---->      ---->
       1/2        1/2        1/2
```

and we make the states $0$, $3$ absorbant, to have a chain.
(So once in $0$ we remain in $0$, once in $3$ we remain in $3$.)

Let $p_k$ be the probability to reach $3$ before $0$, when being in the state $k$.

Of course, $p_0=0$, and $p_3=1$.  Then we have the following linear system of equations:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
p_0 &=0\ ,\\
p_1 &= \frac 12p_0+\frac 12p_2\ ,\\
p_2 &= \frac 12p_1+\frac 12p_3\ ,\\
p_3 &= 1\ .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
The solution is $\boxed{\ p_1=1/3\ }$ and $p_2=2/3$.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have one question. In the system of the equations you wrote $p_1 = \frac{1}{2}p_0 + \frac{1}{2}p_2$, which implies (if I get it correctly), that you *can* move from the zero state to the first state, with the $50\%$ probability. But don't we automatically lose when we have 0 chips? So I think, the formula for $p_1$ should be $p_1 = \frac{1}{2}p_2$. Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Yes, this is right, and in presence of $p_0=0$ it is the same as i wrote. My pedant writing was only trying to follow the general pattern, and in the same time suggest that we land from $1$ in one step either in $0$, or in $2$.

Answer (score 1):

This is call the Gambler's Ruin problem, and there is a very neat, and somewhat technically advanced solution via martingales.  Without going into technical details, the main ideas are:

- Each flip is fair, so the entire game is fair.  You start with $1$ chip, your expected value is still $1$ chip after every flip, and your expected value is still $1$ chip at "game end".
- There is a technical detail concerning how to define game end (called the stopping rule), but trust me that the detail works in your case, where the game ends when you have $0$ or $3$ chips.
- Since your expected value at game end must be $1$ chip, we have:

$$P(\text{end at $0$ chip}) \times 0 + P(\text{end at $3$ chips}) \times 3 = 1$$

which immediately gives $P(\text{end at $3$ chips}) = \frac13$.  The neat thing is that this solution  works for other boundaries (i.e. other definitions of "game end").  E.g. if your game starts at $1$ chip and ends at $-5$ or $+11$ chips, then $P(\text{end at $11$ chips}) = {6 \over 16} = \frac38$.  Obviously you could have gotten the same answer with a Markov Chain / set of recurrences, but this is much faster.

Some more details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin#Fair_coin_flipping) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)) -- and I could have sworn I have seen some online course notes for exactly this treatment.